# Moodle php - "Invalid Sesskey" when creating an account or trying to get forgotten password

Tags: php, moodle

I'm using Moodle 2.7, and a few days ago some users reported to me that when they tried to generate a new account on '/moodle/login/signup.php' or tried to get a forgotten password on '/moodle/login/forgot_password.php'  the "Invalid Sesskey" message error appeared.

Looking for information about the error on Moodle, i found some possible reasons on

'https://docs.moodle.org/24/en/error/moodle/invalidsesskey'

but, I tried all the options and I couldn't solve the issue.

The application is on a production enviroment, and I can send them modifications or tell them what to change but I can't actually see or change their files.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know whether you are using local storage or the database for storing session information? Check the admin page at http://yourmoodle/admin/settings.php?section=sessionhandling and look for the setting at the top (dbsessions).

Answer (score 1):

This should be a comment and then an answer based on your response to that, but apparently I'm too "green" to post comments, so it's a straight up answer I'm afraid.  You mention that the "... users reported to me that when they tried to generate a new account ..." and from this, I'm assuming that they are already users (have their own accounts) and are trying to generate new accounts for other users.

If they brought up this new user signup page whilst logged out, and then logged in on a separate browser tab (for instance, to see that the new user account was in fact created) then you will get this message.  In this instance, the solution is to not try to be both logged in and logged out at the same time.  Log out from the other session, revisit the signup page, fill in the details again, and all should be well; alternatively, create the user within Site Admin --> Users --> Accounts whilst you are logged on instead.